# If $f$ us periodic and even, what I can conclude about of $\int f \;dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, periodic-functions, uniform-integrability

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic, even and differentiable function. If $L>0$ is the minimal period of $f$, what can I conclude about $$I :=\int_{0}^{L} f(x)\; dx?$$

By the hypotheses we have
$$f(0)=f(L) \quad \text{and} \quad f'(0)=0.$$ My intuition tells me that we can conclude that $ I = 0 $. Is this, in general, true?

Comment: Take $g(x)=f(x)+c$ to produce another such function with a different integral.

Comment: You mean odd? If even, then any constant function is even and $I=0$ is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\sin^{2}x$ for a counter-example. Here $L=\pi$ and the integral is strictly positive.

Comment: Are there conditions on $ f $ that make the statement true, that is, $I=0$?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot draw any conclusion about $I$ if $f$ is an even function.

But if $g(x)$ is a periodic odd integrable function and $L$ is the minimum period, then

$$\int\limits_{0}^{L} g(x)\; dx = \frac12 \int\limits_{-L}^{L} g(x)\; dx$$ because $g$ is periodic, while $$\int\limits_{-L}^{L} g(x)\; dx=0$$ because $g$ is odd, so $$\int\limits_{0}^{L} g(x)\; dx = 0.$$

Comment: While $\int_{-L}^{L}g(x)\;dx$?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno $=0$.  Thank you

Comment: This is wrong! The first property is valid for even functions. See for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Analytic_properties).

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno The first property is valid for periodic functions of period $L$, whether they are even or odd or a mixture of the two.  The second is true for odd functions.  So the third is true for periodic odd functions, which was your original question